# Using boost::regex to replace a backslash with double backslash and double quote with a slash quote

Tags: regex, boost, backslash

I'm going batty trying to get this to work. Here's what I have so far, but ça ne marche pas.

```
const std::string singleslash("\\\\\\\\");
const std::string doublequote("\\\"\"\\");
const std::string doubleslash("\\\\\\\\\\\\");
const std::string slashquote("\\\\\\\\\"\\");

std::string temp(Variables);
temp.assign(boost::regex_replace(temp,boost::regex(singleslash),doubleslash,boost::match_default));
temp.assign(boost::regex_replace(temp,boost::regex(doublequote),slashquote,boost::match_default));
```

Someone please save me.

**Update** It seems that I'm not using regex_replace properly. Here's a simpler example that doesn't work either...

```
std::string w("Watermelon");
temp.assign(boost::regex_replace(w,boost::regex("W"),"x",boost::match_all | boost::format_all));
MessageBox((HWND)Window, temp.c_str(), "temp", MB_OK);
```

This gives me "Watermelon" instead of "xatermelon"

**Update 2** Using boost::regex wrong... this one works

```
boost::regex pattern("W");
temp.assign(boost::regex_replace(w,pattern,std::string("x")));
```

**Update 3** Here's what ultimately worked

```
std::string w("Watermelon wishes backslash \\ and another backslash \\ and \"\"fatness\"\"");
temp.assign(w);

MessageBox((HWND)Window, temp.c_str(), "original", MB_OK);

const boost::regex singlebackslashpat("\\\\");
const std::string doublebackslash("\\\\\\\\");
temp.assign(boost::regex_replace(w,singlebackslashpat,doublebackslash));
MessageBox((HWND)Window, temp.c_str(), "double-backslash", MB_OK);

const boost::regex doublequotepat("\"\"");
const std::string backslashquote("\\\\\\\"");
temp.assign(boost::regex_replace(temp,doublequotepat,backslashquote));
MessageBox((HWND)Window, temp.c_str(), "temp", MB_OK);
```

Comment: How exactly does it ne marche pas? Compile-time errors? Complete failure to match at runtime? Wrong replacements at runtime? Crash? Unexpected launching of nuclear warheads?

Comment: Nuclear warheads. ;)  No just kidding - complete failure to match at runtime. All the single-slashes are still there.

Comment: How many backslashes do I really need to tell it to look for one backslash!  Sheesh.

Comment: Actually maybe it really is working, just that when I look at it, the double slashes become one slash? (Update, nope)

Comment: Aha. I think you want `match_default` not `match_all`; the latter seems to have some rather surprising meaning that isn't at all what you want.

Answer (score 3):

So, I'm not a boost::regex expert and don't have Boost conveniently installed where I am right now, but let's try to work this through step by step.

**The patterns to match against**

To match a double-quote in the input, you just need a double-quote in the regex (double-quotes aren't magical in regexes), which means all you need is a string containing a double-quote. `"\""` should be fine.

To match a backslash in the input, you need an escaped backslash in the regex, which means two consecutive backslashes; each of those needs to be doubled again in a string literal. So `"\\\\"`. [EDITED: I typed eight instead of four before, which was a mistake.]

**The output formats**

Again, double-quotes aren't magical in match replacement formats (or whatever the right terminology is) but backslashes are. So to get two backslashes in the output you need four in the string, which means you need 8 in the string literal. So: `"\\\\\\\\"`.

To get a backslash followed by a double-quote, your string needs to be two backslashes and a double-quote, and all of those need to be preceded with backslashes in the string literal. So: `"\\\\\""`.

[EDITED to add the actual code for easier copy-and-pasting:]

```
const std::string singleslash("\\\\");
const std::string doublequote("\"");
const std::string doubleslash("\\\\\\\\");
const std::string slashquote("\\\\\"");
```

**Matching flags**

After reading tofutim's update, I tried to look up `match_all` and found no documentation for it. It does, however, appear to be a possible match flag value, and the header file in which it's defined has the following cryptic comment next to it: "must find the whole of input even if match_any is set". The similarly-cryptic comment attached to `match_any` is "don't care what we match". I'm not sure what any of that means and it seems like these flags are deprecated or something, but in any case you probably don't want to be using them.

(After a very quick look at the source, I think what `match_all` does is to accept a match only if it ends at the end of the input. So you might try replacing `n` instead of `W` in your revised test case and see whether that works. Alternatively, perhaps I missed something and it has to match the entire input, which you could check by replacing `Watermelon` instead of `W` or `n`. Or you could not bother, if you happen not to be curious about this.)

Give that a try and report back...

Answer (score 2):

I have no boost here, but single(back)slash must be written as \\ in regex and thus as c++ string literal is four backslahses. The replacement string has to be escaped and in c++ again, so its eight backslashes.

Double quote in regex must not be escaped, so it is "" and in c++ \"\". The replacement again has to be escaped, so its \\", and of course in c++, so it is \\\\\".

according to your update 3 the patterns and replacement strings must be initialized like this:

```
const std::string singleslashpat("\\\\");
const std::string doublequotepat("\"\"");
const std::string doubleslash("\\\\\\\\");
const std::string slashquote("\\\\\"");
```

Comment: not yet, if i swap out doubleslash and slashquote it seems that the replace is not doing anything at all.

Comment: @tofutim yes, backslash must be escaped in replacement strings also, I'll correct my answer

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that depends, if tofutim wants to replace "" or "... ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah, so it does. It's a shame the term "double-quote" is so ambiguous.

Comment: ok, the regex is right on this one, but it turned out that there was a bug in how i was using boost::regex... for some reason, I can't just put it inside the regex_replace like that.  See update3 for working solution. You can update your answer and I will check it.

Comment: @tofutim so, I edited my answer accordingly, but omitted the boost regex calls for clarity, as your complete solution is already in your question.